how to add callback to v8 correctly
I need to add a callback function that is invoked on each call of a JavaScript function, passing the function name and arguments as parameters
As far as I understand, to achieve this, I can add the following code in the Generate_InterpreterEntryTrampoline function:
{
    FrameScope scope(masm, StackFrame::INTERNAL);
    __ Push(rdi);  // Push the target function.
    __ CallRuntime(Runtime::kHOOK_OnBeforeCall);   
} 

The runtime function itself:
RUNTIME_FUNCTION(Runtime_HOOK_OnBeforeCall) {                  
  
   HandleScope scope(isolate);
   DCHECK_EQ(1, args.length());

   Handle<Object> function_name = args.at(0);
   PrintF("Function Name: %s\n", Cast<String>(*function_name)->ToCString().get());

   return ReadOnlyRoots(isolate).undefined_value();
}
//...
//runtime.h:
//  F(HOOK_OnBeforeCall, 1, 1)          


But when I try to build this code, I get the following error:
`# Fatal error in ..\..\src\builtins\x64\builtins-x64.cc, line 1283
# Check failed: masm->isolate()->heap()->interpreter_entry_return_pc_offset().value() == masm->pc_offset() (448 vs. 450).
`

Could you please help me with this:

What does this error mean? How can I modify the provided code so it compiles?

If I need to log all JavaScript function calls, including user-defined and Web API functions, is it correct to do this in the Generate_InterpreterEntryTrampoline function?

Is it sufficient to do this only in the Generate_InterpreterEntryTrampoline function?



(V8 developer here.)


What does this error mean?


You've violated an assumption that V8 relies on. See the failing check to learn more.

How can I modify the provided code so it compiles?

StackOverflow isn't a "please debug/fix my code for me" service.


If I need to log all JavaScript function calls, including user-defined and Web API functions, is it correct to do this in the Generate_InterpreterEntryTrampoline function?


This approach won't be able to intercept embedder-provided (i.e. "Web API") functions, nor functions that are hot enough to progress from the interpreter to one of the compiled execution tiers. You could force interpreter-only execution to work around the latter. I don't have an idea for the former.
Doing any modifications in handwritten assembly is probably also the hardest way of doing them: you'll have to be really careful with the stack layout (especially if your callback will eventually need to allocate any objects) and register contents. But it can work.


Is it sufficient to do this only in the Generate_InterpreterEntryTrampoline function?


Depends on your needs. See (2.) above.

Have you seen the existing --trace flag, and is it perhaps enough for your needs? If not, you could at least use its implementation for inspiration.
